# reuse stringstream after rdbuf

Tags: c++, stringstream

Is it possible to reuse a stringstream `s` after pushing the buffer to another stream `stream` with the `.rdbuf()` function?

I reconstructed the circumstances:

http://ideone.com/JoPJ1E

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>

ofstream f("t.txt");

void dump(stringstream & s){
    f << s.rdbuf();
    assert(f.good()); // THIS ASSERT FAILS IN my code (see main)
}

void doit1(){

  static std::stringstream s;

  s.str("");
  s.clear();
  s.seekp(0);
  s.seekg(0);

  s << "1";
  dump(s);

}

void doit2(){
  // your code goes here
  std::stringstream s;
  s << "2";
  dump(s);

}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    doit2();
    doit1(); // ASSERT FAILS HERE
}
```

My program does not crash, and there is no output in the text file!
**The assert fails exactly by calling doit1(), why does doit2 set the stream `f` in a bad state??**

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: For me too, but somehow it does not here, try to get a MWE

Comment: What does "it does not here" mean?

Comment: You need to clear the error flags `s.clear()` ***before*** doing anything else. **EDIT:** However your code works for me too.

Comment: Given that `rdbuf()` is a `const` method, there is definitely no "consuming the string".

Comment: There's text output for me (21 as expected)... what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Barry it is `streambuf * rdbuf() const` meaning the stringstream does not change but the streambuf pointed to is not const.It can and I guess will be manipulated by the << operator. I'm humbled to omit that I don't know what MWE is. Microsoft Windows Environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a [long-standing MSVC design issue](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NgADGku05cwJ:https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c%252B%252B/DJpywE3Y6Y4%20&cd=10&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it) by Dinkumware (the STL-provider for Microsoft) when setting a 0-position with seekp on a stream associated with an empty content. Apparently they did this to have the compiler conform to the [Perennial C++ test suite](http://www.peren.com/pages/cppvs_set.htm) and that the standard dictated that.

I find this not very clear with N3797 since *§27.7.3.5 basic_ostream seek members/p3* says

> basic_ostream& seekp(pos_type pos);
>
> 3 Effects: If fail()
>   != true, executes
>
> > **rdbuf()->pubseekpos(pos, ios_base::out)**. In case of
> >     failure, the function calls setstate(failbit) (which may throw
> >     ios_base::failure).
>
> 4 Returns: *this.

And calling `pubseekpos` (equivalent) directly doesn't trigger any bug.

Tested with MSVC2013Update4:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream s;
    s.str("");
    if (s.fail())
        cout << "bad"; // not printed
    s.seekp(0);
    // s.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(0, ios_base::out); // Equivalent as per 27.7.3.5/3
    if (s.fail())
        cout << "bad"; // printed
}
```

[Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d1ba9703fae7337) and [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1afde8a073739a5) work just fine.

Comment: I use gcc and the above problem is still happening (assert in doit1)

Comment: Its about the stream ``f`` which is not good, not the stringstream (see above)

Comment: @Gabriel the stringstream enters in failstate due to this, and please don't downvote if you don't read this as a whole first.

Comment: it seems a good answer, but I cant make any connection why my file stream ``f`` enters failstate, it is not the stringstream.
Is that failstate propagated to the file stream ``f``? Thanks for giving some more clue :-)

Comment: @Gabriel exactly, you're using a `stringstream` in a "failed" state and also having problems reading from it. That's why `f` fails. The root cause is the one I outlined above.